# Pygame: Drawing Lines

Tags: python, if-statement, drawing, pygame

In my previous question [For Loop Functions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168040/for-loop-functions-in-python?noredirect=1#comment26635985_18168040),
I had trouble with putting functions that contained a command to draw a line for a hangman game. It didn't exactly draw the line, and I first suspected it was a problem with the for loop or the functions. Now I realize there is somewhat a glitch with Pygame.

I have tried solving the problem by using this code in the country, CANADA:

```
b2 = font.render(str(letters[1]), True, (red))
screen.blit(b2, (bPosition))
if hangman1x == -500 and hangman1y == -500:
    hangman1x = (775, 250)
    hangman1y = (775, 50)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (hangman1x), (hangman1y), (5))
    pygame.display.flip()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    bPosition = -500, -500
    b1.x, b1.y = -500, -500
if hangman1x == (775, 250) and hangman1y == (775, 50):
    print 'hi'
    width = 6
    pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (hangman1x), (hangman1y), (5))
    print 'yay'
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Now here's the weird thing.

When you press the B blitted onto the screen, it turns red, like its meant to, draws the line perfectly fine, but disappears, when the B disappears, and I understand why. After that, I added that extra if code. (Notice that both `pygame.draw.line`(s) are the same),  It prints hi and yay in the shell, but it does not keep the line. Anyway to solve this?

Comment: I tried running the code in your post, and got `NameError: name 'font' is not defined`. Could you edit in a [short, self contained, correct, runnable example](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits your problem? This will make it much easier for readers to understand what's going wrong, and you'll get more and better answers :-)

Answer (score 1):

After you are calling pygame.draw.line() you are probably redrawing your screen completely white, this will draw over the line and hide it. Instead of drawing lines like you are, I would build a hangman class draw from that

```
class Hangman():
  def __init__(self):
    self.lines = 0 #Number of lines to be drawn

  def draw(self,screen):
    #TODO draw to screen based on self.lines

#More code setting up pygame

drawlist = []
myMan = Hangman()
drawlist.append(myMan)
#mainloop
while 1:
  screen.fill('#000000')
  for item in drawlist:
    item.draw(screen)
```

This way you are redrawing you hangman every frame, and thus he is always being showed

**EDIT Added a running example**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pygame
pygame.init()

class Hangman():
  def __init__(self):
    self.lines = 0 #Number of lines to be drawn

  def hang(self):
    self.lines += 1

  def draw(self,screen):
    for x in range(self.lines):
      coord1 = (x*10,20)
      coord2 = (x*10,50)
      pygame.draw.line(screen,(0,0,0),coord1,coord2)

size = screenWidth,screenHeight = 200,70
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.flip()

myman = Hangman()

drawlist = []
drawlist.append(myman)
#mainloop
running = True
while running:
  #EVENT HANDLING#
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      running = False
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
      if event.key == 32: #Spacebar
        myman.hang()

  #DRAWING#
  screen.fill((255,255,255))
  for item in drawlist:
    item.draw(screen)
  pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: `if event.key == 32:` should be `if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:`

Comment: Thank you for your attempt, but it doesn't seem to work. I suspect it is something with my Mac, or my version of Pygame or something, because it isn't working. I've run your example, but it works, but when I use your code for it, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: @monkey That would be the proper way to do it. I have this bad habit of just printing the events, and looking for the key code in the log. Instead of using the docs like I should

Comment: @user2625902 Are you running the code all by itself? What do you mean by it doesn't work at all? What kind of errors? I would love to help, but sadly I can't when I don't know your errors.